# Array formula issue

Tags: google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, array-formulas

I am trying to turn this into an array formula with the first cell being the header.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ht6brZFTrTpmh7Wr-M-59ulTRPatvAUEu0QBvqbrxhw/edit#gid=357252415", "Data!B:B"),MATCH(A2,IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ht6brZFTrTpmh7Wr-M-59ulTRPatvAUEu0QBvqbrxhw/edit#gid=357252415", "Data!A:A"),0),1))
```

I tried formatting it like this:

```
=ArrayFormula({"Name";IFERROR(INDEX(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ht6brZFTrTpmh7Wr-M-59ulTRPatvAUEu0QBvqbrxhw/edit#gid=357252415", "Data!B:B"),MATCH(A2:A,IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ht6brZFTrTpmh7Wr-M-59ulTRPatvAUEu0QBvqbrxhw/edit#gid=357252415", "Data!A:A"),0),1))})
```

but it is only providing me with the first row value, the rest of the column remains blank.

thanks in advance

Comment: Could you provide sample data we could work on? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fx is correct. make sure you run this first and connect your sheets by allowing access:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("1ht6brZFTrTpmh7Wr-M-59ulTRPatvAUEu0QBvqbrxhw", "Data!B1")
```

when connected use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Name"; IFERROR(INDEX(
 IMPORTRANGE("1ht6brZFTrTpmh7Wr-M-59ulTRPatvAUEu0QBvqbrxhw", "Data!B:B"), MATCH(A2:A,
 IMPORTRANGE("1ht6brZFTrTpmh7Wr-M-59ulTRPatvAUEu0QBvqbrxhw", "Data!A:A"), 0)))})
```

or try:

```
={"Name"; INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, 
 IMPORTRANGE("1ht6brZFTrTpmh7Wr-M-59ulTRPatvAUEu0QBvqbrxhw", "Data!A:B"), 2, 0)))}
```

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. Only showing the first name.

Comment: @cpaone can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: I can try. Some sensitive info on the page. This is what the page looks like https://i.imgur.com/duqzbYI.png

Comment: @cpaone hard to tell like this just from a picture... make sure that both columns A have set the same formatting...

Comment: sorry I actually got it to work.
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Name"; INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, 
 IMPORTRANGE("1ht6brZFTrTpmh7Wr-M-59ulTRPatvAUEu0QBvqbrxhw", "Data!A:B"), 2, 0)))})
works!

I misunderstood how you wanted me to try it.